# Composite key or New Unique key

Tags: mysql, composite-primary-key

I want to know which will be the best.
I am having a table say A having col1(is a foreign key fk1),col2(is also a foreign keyfk2).
Can I use PK as (col1,col2) or a newly generated PK.
The queries will have fk1 in criteria and fk2 in joins.
Kindly suggest me a best one.

P.S I am using mysql

Comment: Is this just a linking table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a many-to-many link table, just use `(col1, col2)` as a `PK`.

Foreign keys in `MySQL` imply `InnoDB` which is index-organized, this means that the table itself will be the `PRIMARY KEY` and it's records will be ordered.

If you are also going to search for `col2` and use `col1` in joins, you'll need to create an additional secondary index on `(col2)`. This index will implicitly include the `PRIMARY KEY` values as the record pointers, and, hence, will in fact be and index on `(col2, col1, col2)`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said - if this is a linking table, use col1,col2 as PK. If on the other hand this table can also be linked TO, then create a new key of its own. You can also put a unique constraint on the col1,col2 pair.